# Is this a nutritional deficiency?

Tags: spinach, nutrition

After taking 1 harvest of spinach, the new leaves in this pot have appeared lighter. Have taken a second harvest yesterday. I have fertilised it with a 19-19-19 soluble fertiliser once after a month of sowing (after taking first harvest, putting only a small amount so as to avoid burn, quarter tsp in 500 ml water and putting half of it.) For comparison, unharvested plants are there in the second image. Is it a nutritional deficiency? The initial potting mix has cocopeat, vermicompost and perlite.

P. S. The weather is hazy here in New Delhi due to pollution so the images have a yellowish tinge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your plants are healthy. But consider that they hate heat. Spinach is happy in North Italy, but in the South, it turns into collard. In other words, tough leaves.